# No one knows or no one know?

Tags: american-english, british-english, non-native-english

Can you tell which of the following sentences are right? And explain why the others are wrong?

1. No one knows the answer.
2. No one know the answer.
3. There is nobody anwering the qustion.
4. There is nobody answered the question.
5. There is nobody answer the questions.
6. There is nobody answers the question.

Thanks.

Comment: It's "no one", not "noone".

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Comment: Sorry I just want to compare the six questions to see which are wrong and which are right. I supposed I can find some answers from here to compare with my lesson.

Comment: Even though I have 6 sentences to compare, they are nearly simillar that can cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No one knows the answer.

This is correct.

> No one know the answer.

This is incorrect. "No one" is singular, just like "one" and "someone", so the plural verb "know" is incompatible.

> There is nobody answering the question.

The grammar of this one is correct, but it has a different meaning.

This would be appropriate if you want to say no one is answering the question *right now*, e.g. if a teacher posed a question to the entire class but no students raised a hand to answer it.

But if you want to say no one knows the answer, you could phrase it as "There is nobody **who can** answer the question."

> There is nobody answered the question.
>   There is nobody answer the question.
>   There is nobody answers the question.

These are all incorrect; you're missing the word "who" in the relative clause. "Nobody answering" is grammatically correct because it's short for "nobody who is answering" (just like "nobody famous"), but that shortcut only works with the -ing verb form.

"There is nobody **who** answer the question" is still incorrect, because "nobody" is singular and "answer" is the plural verb form.

The other two become grammatically correct once you add "who", but again they have a slightly different meaning from the other correct examples. "Nobody who answered" refers to the past; "nobody who answers" suggests repeated, habitual behavior.

For example, you could say, "Every year, I ask my new students when the Battle of Hastings was fought, and there's nobody who answers the question." (Although "...and nobody answers the question" is more idiomatic.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Noone knows the answer. 
   -that's correct.

   2. Noone know the answer. 
      -this is wrong because you're talking about Noon, not you.
   3. There is nobody anwering the qustion. 
      -structure wise, you're correct but you spelt "answering" and "question" wrong.
   4. There is nobody answered the question. 
      -this is wrong because you got your past tense and present tense mixed up. "is" is present", "answered" is wrong".
   5. There is nobody answer the questions.

      - this is wrong because "answer" must be a verb: answering
   6. There is nobody answers the question.
      -look at point 5. (incorrect verb form)

Comment: Thanks very much, but do we say there is nobody answering the question because nobody is the one to do the action or what?

Comment: Nobody writes no one as **noone**. What does **noone** have to do with **noon**. Can you edit your answer? Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.